# UIScrollView do not scroll down to its original position when keyboard disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am facing very strange situation. I want to scroll-up the UIScrollView to visible when keyboard appear on some UITextView, and this part of the code is working fine. But when keyboard disappears, scrollView do not come to its original position. When I drag it then it come to its original position. Following is what I have done. Please guide me what I have missed

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect commentViewFrame = self.detailCommentView.frame;
    commentViewFrame.origin.y += kbSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.detailCommentView setFrame:commentViewFrame];
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.detailCommentView.frame.origin.y - 90);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect commentViewFrame = self.detailCommentView.frame;
    commentViewFrame.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        [self.detailCommentView setFrame:commentViewFrame];
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.detailCommentView.frame.origin.y + 90);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Actually the concept behind scrollview was not clear to me. But now it is clear and change in one line only made the trick.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect commentViewFrame = self.detailCommentView.frame;
    commentViewFrame.origin.y += kbSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.detailCommentView setFrame:commentViewFrame];
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd blindly try using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to see if it works.

Otherwise I'd check whether `commentViewFrame` value is correct when you're hiding the keyboard.

There is also one more thing that I don't know whether is correct. In  `keyboardWillShow` you're referencing `self.detailCommentView.frame.origin.y` but in `keyboardWillHide` you're referencing `self.dopDetailCommentView.frame.origin.y`. Is it alright?

Comment: My mistake, the correct one is self.detailCommentView.frame.origin.y. Let me edit it now, and thanks for reply as well. Let me check either it works or not.

Comment: I could not understand the first part of your solution. Will you please share some code. Thanks

Comment: I'd try replacing `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` in your code and see if it works

Comment: I have replaced it but nothing happened. Also commentViewFrame value is correct.